# jsPDF.html method doesn't recognize the image quality option

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf

Method `jsPDF.html()` has an option to set the `image` quality (HTMLOptionImage) but this does not seem to affect the image quality or inevitably the document size at all.

My goal is to get the PDF document size down to a reasonable level, but anytime I add images, it blows it up way larger than it needs to be.  Like even a 50kb image file on the document turns it into a 1 MB PDF.

It also seems `compress` doesn't really affect it, the PDF is the same size either way.

Example code using an external image (may have to run this on your local).

package.json running "react": "^17.0.2", and "jspdf": "^2.3.1",

```
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";

const stackoverflow = () => {

function downloadMe() {
    const ele = document.querySelector('#stackoverflowexample');

    const pdf = new jsPDF({
        orientation: 'p',
        unit: 'px',
        format: 'letter',
        compress: true,
        putOnlyUsedFonts: true,
        hotfixes: ['px_scaling'] // an array of hotfix strings to enable
    });

    pdf.html(ele, {
        image: { quality: 10, type: "jpeg" },
        x: 10,
        y: 10,
        callback: function (doc) {
            doc.save(); // File size is huge even though images are small kb
            // attachment = doc.output('datauristring');
        },
    });
}

return (
    <div id="stackoverflowexample">
        <h1>PDF</h1>
        <button onClick={downloadMe}>Download Button</button>
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Borobudur-Temple-Park_Elephant-cage-01.jpg/320px-Borobudur-Temple-Park_Elephant-cage-01.jpg" />
        <p>Image makes PDF larger than it should have to be</p>
    </div>)
}

export default stackoverflow;
```

Answer (score 0):

So I can solve this file size issue by selectively removing and re-adding those image elements with an `addImage` but it doesn't address the underlying problem that the `.html` method is blowing up the img element data sizes.

```
        html2canvas: {
            onclone: (doc) => {
                let target = doc.querySelector("#stackoverflowexample");
                let images = target.querySelectorAll("img");

                let targetRect = target.getBoundingClientRect();
                
                images.forEach((img) => {
                    let rect = img.getBoundingClientRect();
                    pdf.addImage(img, "JPEG", targetRect.x - rect.x, targetRect.y - rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
                    img.remove();
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The image object has a multiplier property, try using that, it will effect the quality of the image and this would result in a greater or lesser file size depending upon what value you set of multiplier

```
image: { quality: 10, type: "jpeg", multiplier: .5 }
```